# Matlab Engine and ROS Library Incompatible?

Tags: ros, matlab, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

i am trying to establich a connection between Matlab 2012a and ROS fuerte. For the beginning i tried to modify the Listener/Talker tutorial. I just included the matlab api in the listener.cpp. It took me some time until i could compile the package with make. I changed the CMakeLists.txt in the beginner_tutorials folder in the following way and it seemed to work:

include_directories(/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/extern/include)
link_directories(/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86)
link_directories(/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86)

target_link_libraries(listener libeng.so)

But when i want to start a node now, i get the following errors:

/home/simon/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/bin/listener: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so)

Are there some libs that are incompatible? Is there a way to fix that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33326/matlab-engine-and-ros-library-incompatible?/) by [mikemodanoxxx](https://answers.ros.org/users/2315/mikemodanoxxx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sj haque](https://answers.ros.org/users/1584/sj-haque/) on 2012-05-05**:
I think you are using ipc bridge to connect if I am not wrong. I posted the solution to this problem in your previous question  http://answers.ros.org/question/33279/matlab-ros-communication-with-ipc_bridge_ros . do check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MATLAB bundles its own libstdc++.so.6, which is generally older than the system-provided version.  In my case, MATLAB is bundling libstdc++.so.6.0.13, whereas my distribution provides libstdc++.so.6.0.17.

You can try to replace the symlinks to libstdc++.so.6 in /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnx86 and /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86 to point to your system-installed version in /usr/lib.  README.libstdc++ in /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/sys/os/glnx86 seems to indicate that at least that version is just included as a convenience.  As long as the SOVERSION is the same and your system version is newer, you should be OK (and if MATLAB doesn't start, just put the symlinks back to the libstdc++ in your matlab installation folder.)  I just changed the symlinks on my MATLAB installation to point to the distribution's libstdc++, it looks like I don't have any issues.

---

Originally posted by [rmattes](https://answers.ros.org/users/1748/rmattes/) with karma: 71 on 2012-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using a different glibc version on your system from the one the debs are built against you will need to compile all of ROS from source against your custom version.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1